# Give href to a php variable

Tags: php, echo, quotes

I want to give href link to the variable below;

```
echo "<td>" . $row['userid'] . "</td>";
```

So that admin can click on that ID and in the other page admin can see all details about the user, using this id.

I tried;

```
    echo "<td><a href="http://www.google.com">" . $row['userid'] . "</a></td>";
```

and

```
    echo "<td>"<a href="http://www.google.com"> . $row['userid'] . </a>"</td>";
```

But they didn't work. Thanks in advance.

edit:
Thanks to @Gautam the answer I'm looking for is below;

```
echo "<td><a href='http://www.google.com'>". $row['expiry'] . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: [Quotes inside quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: what has this got to do with mysql?

Comment: `echo "<td><a href='http://www.google.com'>" . $row['expiry'] . "</a></td>";`

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
echo "<td><a href='http://www.google.com/'". $row['expiry'] .">Click Here</a></td>";
```

or else

```
?>
<td><a href="http://www.google.com/<?php echo $row['expiry'] ?>">Click Here</a></td>
```

Comment: @D4V1D cz i `?>` close php on above of that line

Comment: Yeah, so what? Closing PHP is irrelevant. You are still missing the `echo`.

Comment: That's a good solution sir, but I wanted to Show the 'expiry' instead of 'click here'

Comment: change this `Click Here</a>` to this `Expiry</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You are gettting error because of quotes. Change the quotes for href to single quotes like below and should work fine.

```
 echo "<td><a href='http://www.google.com'>". $row['expiry'] . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: Sorry i missed the quotes. you can try the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use single quotas for your link. If you are using double quotas you will close your echo instead of opening quotas within other quotas:

```
echo "<td><a href='http://www.google.com'>" . $row['expiry'] . "</a></td>";
```

Otherwise you also could use \ in order to escape the double quotas:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">" . $row['expiry'] . "</a></td>";
```